# Python Map function, can I iterate functions, not input?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, lambda

I am studying lambda function of Python.
I have a list of functions, say fs, and a constant, say c.
I need to iterate fs, with input c, without using for or while loop, and store all the result in a list. Is such a thing possible with map function? I believe only input can be iterated for it. Is there any other clever way?

Comment: Add more relevant details to the question

Comment: `map(lambda f: f(c), fs)`?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.
Review the documentation on `map` and try to apply it to your situation.

Comment: Thank you, I am doing it for the assignment so I think I cannot add details. I tried map(lambda f: f(c), fs), but c doesn't resolve in the function. I am nesting lambda function and c is declared outer lambda function. So I think it should be in the scope but somehow it doesn't work.

Comment: Then we *will* need details, as that will certainly work in general.

Answer (score 1):

> Is such a thing possible with map function?

Yes.

```
results = list(map(lambda f: f(c), fs))
```

But it's easier with a list comprehension:

```
results = [f(c) for f in fs]
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not allowed to use loop so I go for the first one... actually I'm nesting lambda function, and c does not resolve in (lambda f: f(c)). ..

Comment: @Max Well a list comprehension is not really a loop, even if `for` appears in it. But `map()` works, too.

Comment: OK,  I tried map(lambda f: f(c), fs), but c doesn't resolve I am nesting lambda function and c is declared outer lambda function. So I think it should be in the scope but somehow it doesn't work.

Comment: @Max Hard to tell without seeing your code. As the others have said, you need to add more context to your question.

Comment: You are right. Thank you anyway!